# Existence of a global min

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that the function $f(x,y) = (x^2+y+4)^2 + (x^2-y)^2$ has a global min.  The function is a sum of squares so it's bounded below by $0$, but this isn't enough to prove it has a global min.

Comment: What are your requirements for a global min?

Comment: @ Carlos Eugenio http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima

Comment: note that this is $2(x^2+2)^2+2(y+2)^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x,y) = 2(x^2 +2)^2 +2(y+2)^2$$
$$\frac{df}{dx} = 8x(x^2 +2)=0$$
$$x=0$$
$$\frac{df}{dy} = 4(y+2)=0$$
$$y=-2$$

The only minmum is where $x=0$ and $y=-2$.  Everywhere else the function is always increasing away from that point.

$$\frac{d^2f}{dx^2} = 24x^2 +16$$
$$\frac{d^2f}{dy^2} = 4$$
$$\frac{d^2f}{dxdy} = 0$$

so the limits as $x$ and $y$ go to infinity are not lower as the second derivatives are always positive.

Comment: I made a mistake... damn

Comment: Corrected... I accidentally changed a plus to a minus.